# SharePoint 2013 search schema - can't select date time for new managed property

Tags: 2013, search, managed-property, crawled-property

I need to create a new managed property for a date/time field in a list. Unfortunately, when I try to create a new managed property it will only allow me to select "Text" and "Yes/No".
If I cannot setup SharePoint to create such managed properties, how can I achieve that in a search items with a date less than "today" should be discarded?
I have system permissions - so I don't think it be a permissions issue.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue of SharePoint Online. To workaround this issue, you can use the `RefinableDatexx` properties.

These are OOTB properties, just map your crawled properties to one of the `RefinableDatexx` managed properties and you will be able to use it in your code/webparts.

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! I used this on SP 2013 on-prem.

Comment: This should work fine. Well answered. Upvoted.